# iOS, Xcode - working with international file names in code

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Objective-C and Cocoa Touch framework.

I have few image files in my iPhone application. Some file names are in English and some are in Japanese like **"ココ奈ごろにゃんIcon.png"**.

I'm creating views programatically and not using IB.

My code is not able to read files with name in Japanese language. How can I get this work done?

Comment: Can you post examples of your code to read these files?

Comment: Is your source code in UTF-8?

Comment: After changing to UTF-8, the problem solved......

Answer (score 0):

You should change your source code's encoding to **Unicode (UTF-8)** or **Unicode (UTF-16)**.

**File Inspector -> Text Settings -> Text Encoding**

[image: Text Encoding option]